Z-transform of the Unit Step and DTFT
In class we showed the the z transform of the unit step only exists for |z|>1 but we also calculated the DTFT of the unit step. Does convergence on the unit circle imply the DTFT exists but not the other way around? What are interesting cases of this relationship?

Assuming that the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform $X(z)$ of a sequence $x[n]$ exists, there are three cases we need to distinguish when considering the relation between $X(z)$ and the corresponding DTFT $X_F(e^{j\omega})$. Let the region of convergence (ROC) of $X(z)$ be $r<|z|<R$ with $0\le r<R$:

$r<1$ and $R>1$, i.e., the unit circle is inside the ROC. In that case we simply obtain the DTFT from the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform by replacing $z$ by $e^{j\omega}$: $X_F(e^{j\omega})=X(e^{j\omega})$

$r>1$ or $R<1$, i.e., the unit circle is not inside the ROC. In this case, the DTFT doesn't exist.

$r=1$ or $R=1$, i.e., the ROC is limited by the unit circle, and there are $K$ simple poles on the unit circle: $p_k=e^{j\omega_k}$, $k=0,1,\ldots K-1$. In that case, the DTFT is given by


$$X_F(e^{j\omega})=\pi\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}a_k\delta(\omega-\omega_k)+X(e^{j\omega}),\qquad -\pi\le\omega<\pi\tag{1}$$
where $a_k$ are the residues of the poles.
The unit step sequence is an example of case $3$ above with just one simple pole at $z=1$ with residue $a_0=1$ (i.e., $K=1$ and $\omega_0=0$). Consequently, with
$$X(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}$$
we obtain from $(1)$ for the DTFT of the unit step sequence
$$X_F(e^{j\omega})=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}},\qquad -\pi\le\omega<\pi\tag{2}$$
Equation $(1)$ can be generalized to poles on the unit circle with multiplicity greater than $1$. In that case, the DTFT contains derivatives of the Dirac impulse.
See this question and its answers for different ways to derive the DTFT of the unit step sequence.

EDIT (for Robert):
We know that the real part of the DTFT of a sequence equals the DTFT of its even part. The even part of the unit step sequence $u[n]$ is
$$\frac12\big(u[n]+u[-n]\big)=\frac12+\frac{\delta[n]}{2}\tag{3}$$
The DTFT of $(3)$ is $\pi\delta(\omega) + \frac12$. This must equal the real part of the DTFT given by Eq. $(2)$. To see this, let's rewrite $(2)$:
\begin{align*}
\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}} & = \pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\cdot\frac{1+1}{1-e^{-j\omega}} \\
&= \pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\cdot\frac{1-e^{-j\omega}+1+e^{-j\omega}}{1-e^{-j\omega}} \\
&= \pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\left[1+\frac{1+e^{-j\omega}}{1-e^{-j\omega}}\right] \\
&= \pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\left[1-j\cot\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)\right]\tag{4}
\end{align*}
We see that the real part of $(4)$ equals $\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12$, as expected.
As a side result we obtain the DTFT of the discrete-time signum sequence:
$$\operatorname{sgn}[n]=\begin{cases}1,&n>0\\0,&n=0\\-1,&n<0\end{cases}\tag{5}$$
The odd part of $u[n]$ is
$$\frac12\big(u[n]-u[-n]\big)=\frac12\operatorname{sgn}[n]\tag{6}$$
Its DTFT is $j$ times the imaginary part of $(4)$.
Hence,
$$\operatorname{DTFT}\big\{\operatorname{sgn}[n]\big\}=-j\cot\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)\tag{7}$$

Matt, what is the value of $u[0]$?

@robertbristow-johnson: We're in discrete time, so the only definition I've ever come across is $u[0]=1$.

That's normally the case for me.  Now what happens when you add $u[n] + u[-n]$?  Does that give you the result you want regarding the Fourier or Z transform $\mathscr{F}{u[n]} + \mathscr{F}{u[-n]}$ ?  So $$ u[n] + u[-n] = 1 + \delta[n] $$ where $\delta[n]$ is the Kronecker delta.

And, Matt, if you're putting $e^{j \omega}$ in the argument of $X_\mathscr{F}(\cdot)$, the function is identical to the Z transform and you don't need the ${}_\mathscr{F}$ subscipt.

@robertbristow-johnson: Yes to your first question. And I use the subscript because in general the two functions aren't identical. The unit circle being inside the ROC of the Z-transform is a special case.

What does $$ \mathscr{F}\big{ u[n]\big} + \mathscr{F}\big{ u[-n]\big} $$ add to?

@robertbristow-johnson: Tell me, what's bothering you? That's faster and easier than me answering your test questions :)

$$ \begin{align} \mathscr{F}\big{u[n]\big} + \mathscr{F}\big{u[-n]\big} &= \mathscr{F}\big{\delta[n]\big}+ \mathscr{F}\big{1\big} \ \ &= 1 + 2\pi \delta(\omega) \ \end{align}$$
I wanna see that $1$ on the rhs be a $\frac{1}{1-\cos(\omega)}$  but it's not.

Actually, I wonder if it's
$$ \begin{align} \mathscr{F}\big{u[n]\big} + \mathscr{F}\big{u[-n]\big} &= \mathscr{F}\big{\delta[n]\big}+ \mathscr{F}\big{1\big} \ \ &= \frac{1}{1-\cos(\omega)} + \sum_k 2\pi \delta(\omega - 2\pi k) \ \end{align}$$

$1+2\pi\delta(\omega)$ is correct. It's exactly twice the real part of Eq. (2), as it should be. Note that the real part of $1/(1-e^{-j\omega})$ is $\frac12$. So everything works out ...

I don't see it all working out yet.  And $X(e^{j\omega})$ must be periodic with period $2 \pi$, no matter what.

I know there is mathematical history.  Probably 4 decades ago, when I was a grad student, I hammered this out to my own satisfaction.  But I'm not satisfied now.  (You're not on the hook, I'm just not satisfied.)

@robertbristow-johnson: Check out my updated answer.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-e^{j\omega}} + \frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}} &= \frac{1-e^{-j\omega}}{(1-e^{j\omega})(1-e^{-j\omega})} + \frac{1-e^{j\omega}}{(1-e^{j\omega})(1-e^{-j\omega})}\
\
&= \frac{1-e^{-j\omega}}{1-e^{j\omega}-e^{-j\omega}+1} + \frac{1-e^{j\omega}}{1-e^{j\omega}-e^{-j\omega}+1}\
\
&= \frac{1-e^{-j\omega}}{2 - 2\cos(\omega)} + \frac{1-e^{j\omega}}{2 - 2\cos(\omega)}\
\
&= \frac{1-e^{-j\omega}+1-e^{j\omega}}{2 - 2\cos(\omega)} \
\
&= \frac{2 - 2\cos(\omega)}{2 - 2\cos(\omega)} \
\
&= 1 \
\end{align}$$

I didn't realize that.  So I would say that the DTFT of the discrete unit step $u[n]$ is:
$$ \mathscr{F}\big{u[n] \big} = \pi \sum_{k\ \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(\omega - 2\pi k) + \frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}} $$
That is periodic in $\omega$ with period $2\pi$ as it should be.

@robertbristow-johnson: That's right, I'm just too lazy to always write an infinite sum for Dirac deltas in an expression for a DTFT. I added $-\pi\le\omega<\pi$ to Eq. (2) to make this explicit.

There is a technical nitpick that we don't usually care about in DSP, but by Pontryagin duality, the dual of a discrete domain (here time) must be compact (here frequency), yet the real line extended to $\pm\infty$ is not compact. Hence it is technically correct to stay in the compact domain of length $2\pi$ assumed identified at the ends. The infinite real line in this context is a lift into a locally (but not globally) compact cover $\mathbb{R}$. We make this sensible by requiring $2\pi$ periodicity of all functions in the cover.
